# Woocommerce Variation Price not show on Single Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use slightly modified template from my Child theme, and into file **content-single-product.php** i use this code:

```
<?php 
         global $product;
        if ($product->is_type( 'simple' )) { ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php 
        if($product->product_type=='variable') {
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $variation_id=$available_variations[0]['variation_id']; // Getting the variable id of just the 1st product. You can loop $available_variations to get info about each variation.
        $variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
        $regular_price = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
        $sales_price = $variable_product1 ->sale_price;
        echo $regular_price+$sales_price;
        }
        ?>
```

But for some strange reason for me i see just one variation price, first one. I need to show all variation options. I know that i missing varition loop, but dont know where to find it so i can combine my function with that code. Any help?

Comment: The code you shared is for `single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` file not for the `content-single-product.php` file.

Comment: I updated my question, pls check it.

Answer (score 0):

I finished to find working code myself.

```
<?php 
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){ ?>

        <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 
'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>"><?php echo $product- 
 >get_price_html(); ?></p>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 
'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 10 );?>

        <?php } elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){ ?>
        <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 
'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>"><?php echo $product- 
 >get_price_html(); ?></p>
        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 
'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 10 );
        ?>

        <?php } ?>
```